# finding complex roots to equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, roots

I have an equation $x^4+4x^3+8x^2 +8x +4 =0$
which is the characteristic polynomial of a Homogeneous ODE. To solve it, i need to roots of this polynomial but i do not know how to go about finding the roots to it. I do not necessarily need the answer, but a method for finding the complex roots would be good.

THank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: we have
$$
x^4+4x^3+8x^2 +8x +4 =(x^2 + 2x + 2)^2
$$

Comment: oh jesus christ

Comment: fair enough thanks man

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: any shortcut you used to jsut see that?

Comment: *Hint:*  See if $p(x-1)$ can easily be factored..

Answer (score 1):

Here are some tricks for finding both real and complex roots of a quartic equation easily: http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/EMAT6680Fa09/Davenport/Solving%20Quartic%20Equations.pdf

In addition, on your case,an excellent root finder, for polynomials of all grades: https://xrjunque.nom.es/rootfinder.aspx should work fine:

```
Complex roots:
Root 1: -1.00000000785058-i*0.999999991137563
Root 2: -1.00000000785058+i*0.999999991137563
Root 3: -0.999999992149423-i*1.00000000886244
Root 4: -0.999999992149423+i*1.00000000886244
```

or $r_1 = -1 + i$,
   $r_2 = -1 - i$,
   $r_3 = r_1$,
   $r_4 = r_2$.

I hope this would help! Happy night! :-)